# Koan Support Issue

Tags: javascript

I need a little help with the code listed below.  I'm working with Koans right now and am stuck on a problem...Probably making it more difficult than what it should be.  If anyone can help me out that would be great...Just need to know what goes in "FILL_ME_IN".

```
// Some ways of asserting equality are better than others.
it('should assert equality a better way', function() {
var expectedValue = FILL_ME_IN;
var actualValue = 1 + 1;

// toEqual() compares using common sense equality.
expect(actualValue).toEqual(expectedValue);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: `2`. But seriously, for `actualValue` you'd normally use some sort of function output and for `expectedValue` you'd write down what you expect `actualValue` to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rogier Spieker mentioned, a more real world example would be something like

Your code, usually in a separate file

```
   function addNumbers(a,b){
        return a +b;
    }
```

Your tests

```
it('adds two numbers', function() {
var actualValue = addNumbers(1,1);

// toEqual() compares using common sense equality.
expect(actualValue).toEqual(2);
});
```

Comment: so the "FILL_ME_IN" should be replaced with 'expect(actualValue).toEqual(2);'?  When I do that it's undefined.  I do understand what you are saying about creating the function in a seperate file but this is just to pass this exercise as I slowly work my way through the language.

Comment: If you just want to get this to work, `FILL_ME_IN` should be 2.  As in, `var expectedValue = 2;`  What is the exact error message you receive?  What is undefined exactly?

Comment: 'Expected undefined to equal 2.'  I can't just put in 2 because it needs to solve the problem a particular way...it needs to solve it as described in the comments.  Irritating...

Comment: Just forget it...not sure what's going on...Koans seems a bit picky about choosing the exact method they are looking for...I will just run through a bunch, I'm sure I'll get it.  Thanks for your help.